# Blank message for block UI?

Tags: angularjs, blockui

I'm using Block-UI for Angular & I'm getting a blank message.   Has anyone else seen this?  I've set a message in the start(), message() functions & BlockUIConfig.message property, but I don't get a message.  Block UI is working otherwise.

UPDATE - Code Sample

```
  blockUI.start("Getting data...");
    $http.get(url+"/rest/get/data").success(function(response)
    {
        $scope.grid.rowData = response.data;
        $scope.grid.api.onNewRows();
        blockUI.stop();

    }).error(function(response)
        {
            window.alert(response);
            blockUI.reset();
        }
    );
```

UPDATE 2 - Getting this error on the console

> Error: No parent block-ui service instance located.
>       at blkUI.directive.scope (http://localhost:8080/mdp-js/assets/block-ui/angular-block-ui.js:163:13)

Comment: Can you paste some sample code?

Comment: Code sample  attached.  Block UI pops up when expected but there is no text,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui/issues/29) had a fix for this issue.  Look for the response from yyanavichus  on Sep 22, 2014.  I made that change to angular-block-ui.js & block-ui works fine for me now.

Answer (score 1):

If you give text with message key it will work. like below -

```
blockUI.start( { message: "Getting data..."} );
```

I believe you have injected `blockUI` in controller.

Comment: Same result.  No message.